# gedit bookmarks not saved

Tags: gedit, bookmarks

Problem:

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + B to mark a bookmark (bookmark gets highlighted in green, and with an icon in the left margin)
2. Close the file, or gedit
3. Re-open the file, or gedit
4. RESULT: the bookmark is not saved (the bookmark disappeared)

Software:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- gedit 41.0
- gedit-plugin-bookmarks 41.0

The gedit bookmarks plugin has worked well for me in the past. But I recently re-installed Ubuntu, and I have no idea why it is not saving the bookmarks now.

I wonder where do the bookmarks are stored. Maybe I am missing the directory, or file, where the bookmarks are stored?